how to model a polynomial function with many features and multiple outputs
With linear regression (and multiple linear regression), one can have many features but only one output as y. I need to build a model with multiple x's that also outputs multiple y's in a polynomial fit. What i'm trying to do is to estimate the trajectory of a ball over x seconds thrown by a person using features such as weight, height, arm length, baseball experience in years. So the explanatory variables will be as x's weight, height, arm length, experience, and the different y's will be altitude after throw at 0.5seconds, 1seconds, 2 seconds, 3seconds, 4 seconds. As one can imagine, maybe the larger the weight, and larger the height, and more years of experience would yield a different output in those 5 y's versus someone not. So ideally the function would take those inputs and output the 0.5seconds, 1seconds, 2 seconds, 3seconds, 4 seconds.
also wondering if just doing 5 separate multiple linear regressions would be ok for the 5 different time outputs...?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Whether linear or nonlinear, single or multiple dependent variables, you are always going to start from a parametrized model and fit the parameters to minimize an error function; for example, you could try and fit a model with five different quadratic polynomials (one for each of the altitudes at different time instants) in four variables (one for each of the independent features). By the way, if all those coefficients are estimated independently that's a lot of parameters and a lot of opportunity for overfitting! Moreover, with independent coefficients and an error function that is the sum of five individual errors, there is zero added value in the multidimensional model: the total error can be minimized by estimating the optimal parameters for each of the five polynomials separately. A single multidimensional model is only useful if you have a more complicated, inter-dimensional error function to minimize or if some of the parameters are shared between the five functions.

Hi @Lieven, thanks for your response. I agree with your thoughts and therefore I am having a hard time thinking an approach about this. The parameter variables such as weight, height, arm length, and experience could predict the trajectory at 5 of those time snapshots, and we know that the 5 time snapshots are related in a curvature way. I was thinking of using the parameter variables and output not 5 separate values but the entire polynomial curve. Is that possible?

Sure, but you should not confuse the more-or-less quadratic time dependency of altitude with the quadratic-or-other-degree regression on the coefficients. The quadratic time dependency may appear a priori to have 3 degrees of freedom, but one of those is fixed by the altitude being $0$ at $t=0$ and another one by the rate of gravitational acceleration, which should not depend on who is throwing; which would mean that the problem again becomes a (polynomial) regression with a single dependent variable.
